# PHP 5.6, MSQL 2005

Tags: php, sql-server-2005

I am trying to connect PHP 5.6 to Microsoft SQL 2005, but it says 
"ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server does not support connections to SQL Server 2000 or earlier versions." Thank you very much for your help.

heres my php info
[sqlsrv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aupuz.png)

Comment: What is your version of PHP Driver for SQL? Or how do you connect to SQL Server - mssql extension for PHP, odbc functions, PHP Driver for SQL Server?

Comment: Which Ms SQL Server are you using?

Comment: I use sqlsrv_connect() and in my php.ini:
extension = php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
extension = php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll

Comment: @Arvind MSQL 2005 Express Edition

Comment: @WesleySnopes         What does <?echo phpinfo()?> says about sqlsrv section?

Comment: I've edited the post, to show what phpinfo shows about sqlsrv

Comment: check out this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/example-application-pdo-sqlsrv-driver?view=sql-server-2017) using PDO

Comment: You need to have ODBC installed in your computer.
check this link
http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php

Comment: Thank you all, I really appreciate the time. I'll try those links.